# How to show values from ListView

Tags: android, list, listview, android-listview

I would like to show data from selected ListView
I have List Data

```
public static List<Object>getDataList() throws ParseException {         
    List<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();              
    for(int j=0;j<rankVaccine.size();j++){
        list.add(new DateOfVaccine("Month " + rankVaccine.get(j).getVRank()));
        for(int i = 0;i<vac.size();i++){
            if(vac.get(i).getVRank()==rankVaccine.get(j).getVRank()){
                list.add(new EntityVeccine(vac.get(i).getVDname()));
            }
        }
    }                        
    return list;
}
```

And I would like to show name of Vaccine from seleted position on listView

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BabyVac = new BabyVaccine();
    vaccine = new EntityVeccine(null);
    BabyID = BabyVac.BabyID;

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.baby_vaccine_fragment, container, false);
    final ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.vaccine_list);               

    try {
        listView.setAdapter(new BabyVaccineAdapter(getActivity(), BabyVac.getDataList()));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {             
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {                          
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "position"+listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                    
                Intent goNext = new Intent().setClass(getActivity(), BabyVaccineInsert.class);
                goNext.putExtra("idBaby", BabyID);
                startActivity(goNext);
            }
        });

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return view;        
}
```

went I Toast Data output is Entity.EntityVaccine@223b5cc8 .

But really I want name's vaccine.

Comment: This really should be tagged with Android.

Comment: what seems to be the issue?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).